# Observable timer ticks slows down with time

Tags: angular, timer, rxjs, observable

I am using the observable timers to calculate the time left for an auction and don't want to depend on the client side time. So, I make a service call to our API which returns the localized time and then I create the observable timer which is called after each 1 second where I could add 1 second to the server time to replicate the current server time on client end.

The issue is, after each 15 minutes, there is a gap of around 6 seconds between what the server time is and what our timer is giving. In an hour, the difference increases to around 40 seconds and it continues to increase as long as we don't refresh or reopen the page.

I know that sounds silly but the observable timer which is being called after 1 second interval is slowing down a little (3 seconds in each 10 minutes or so).

Here's the code I am using:

```
//get the server date
this.service.getServerTime().subscribe(serverDate => {
    this.serverDate = serverDate;
}, error => { });
```

To start the timer, I am using

```
//start the timer using observable
let timer = Observable.timer(1000, 1000);
this.timerSubscription = timer.subscribe((t: any) => {
    this.timerExecuted();
});

private timerExecuted(): void {
    if (!this.serverDate) {
        return;
    }       
    //add 1 second to the server date
    this.serverDate.setSeconds(this.serverDate.getSeconds() + 1);

    //console log the server date after adding 1 second
    console.log(this.serverDate);
}
```

When I check the `console.log(this.serverDate)`, initially it starts with the correct date. Assume the time was: `07:15:00PM`, after exactly an hour, the time logged will be `08:14:20PM`. After exact 24 hours, strangely enough, the time logged is around `06:45PM` which is way off target.

The main target is to get the server time running on client in real time without having to depend on the user's local clock. I get the current time from server when the user lands in angular, start the timer using observable (1 second interval) and add seconds in the server time that I received. The ticks I receive from observable significantly slows down over the period of few minutes.

Comment: This essentially uses `setTimeout` internally, which isn't meant to provide perfect clock accuracy. It might be easiest to synchronize with your server time every n seconds or so.

Comment: @IngoBürk This will overload the server because its a live auction site with many auctions! Sending a call to server for each auction/user/second will create so many calls to server

Comment: You don't have to make the call every second, just regularly rather than only initially. You can also use the server time as the start, but rely on the client time differences to get a more accurate time increment (if you want that).

Comment: Wow great, this sounds reasonable! Thanks a lot!

Comment: In your specific case it might also make sense to increase accuracy === frequency of server calls as the auction enters, say, its last minute. That would drastically reduce load across the platform assuming auctions don't all end at the same time..

Answer (score 0):

We noticed that at some point the intervals increased 4x. Turns out that some browsers throttle timers to only fire once per second when out of focus (inactive tab) to save battery.

Some additional information can be found [here](https://news.thewindowsclub.com/google-chrome-ships-a-new-feature-to-increase-the-battery-life-101417/), [here](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode/issues/377) or [here](https://github.com/turuslan/HackTimer).